# What can I do to get the most out of png compression for an image with animation frames?

Tags: animation, compression, png, tiles, clipping

I'm looking to do some javascript powered animation via image clipping. Here's an example of what I'm talking about: http://www.def-logic.com/_dhtml/freejack/hero1.gif

I know png uses a kind of prediction in its compression, what would be the best way to lay out an image like the one above so that I get the most out of the compression? I'm especially interested when the images are very similar, more so than the one above, so there is a lot of potential for compression due to redundancy.

For example, is there specific size of tile that would work well?

Answer (score 0):

> For example, is there specific size of tile that would work well?

Not really. PNG prediction is strictly local (it uses the 3 neighbours pixels), and the prediction  ("filter") strategy can be chosen on a line basis.

That kind of redundancy is not very detectable in PNG compression (not in JPG or practically any other, actually).

If you have the freedom to select the distribution of tiles (few or many per row), you can try vary that, it can have some small influence (to have an image with many short lines instead of few long lines can give the filter better opportunities to select different filters) but, again, I'd bet that the difference will be very small.